# Momentum and conservation of momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

If an object that is moving collides with an object that is at rest and then they both move together what are the momentum and speed changes that take place

Comment: I think you can find the answer in thousands of web pages.

Comment: Is the collision elastic or anelastic?

Answer (score 1):

Total Energy and Total momentum (of both objects) are conserved before and after the collision.

Write the total energy and the total momentum of both objects before and after the collision, equate them and see what you get.

Comment: I downvoted because kinetic energy is not conserved in inelastic collisions.

Comment: @Ben51 This answer does not mention kinetic energy.

Comment: @PM2Ring It is implied.  There is no other relevant form of energy.  In order to really invoke conservation of total energy here, you'd need to include thermal energy.  And there is obviously no way to do that. Whereas, if it was an elastic collision, the correct thing to do would be to write down an equation for conservation of total (aka kinetic) energy.

Comment: I assumed the collision to be elastic, of course. You're right in your downvote, I should have been more precise.